# sum of weights should be exactly 1.0 no matter on which platform it is

Tags: c++

I have such a function that calculates weights according to Gaussian distribution:

```
const float dx = 1.0f / static_cast<float>(points - 1);
const float sigma = 1.0f / 3.0f;
const float norm = 1.0f / (sqrtf(2.0f * static_cast<float>(M_PI)) * sigma);
const float divsigma2 = 0.5f / (sigma * sigma);
m_weights[0] = 1.0f;

 for (int i = 1; i < points; i++)
 {
     float x = static_cast<float>(i)* dx;
     m_weights[i] = norm * expf(-x * x * divsigma2) * dx;
     m_weights[0] -= 2.0f * m_weights[i];
 }
```

In all the calc above the number does not matter. The only thing matters is that `m_weights[0] = 1.0f;` and each time I calculate `m_weights[i]` I subtract it twice from `m_weights[0]` like this:

```
m_weights[0] -= 2.0f * m_weights[i];
```

to ensure that `w[0] + 2 * w[i] (1..N)` will sum to `exactly 1.0f`. But it does not. This assert fails:

```
float wSum = 0.0f;
for (size_t i = 0; i < m_weights.size(); ++i)
{
    float w = m_weights[i];
    if (i == 0) {
        wSum += w;
    } else {
        wSum += (w + w);
    }

}
assert(wSum == 1.0 && "Weights sum is not 1.");
```

How can I ensure the sum to be `1.0f` on all platforms?

Comment: Are you sure it's not due to the limited precision of floating-point numbers in computing?

Comment: You can't. Read the Goldberg paper in Alex's answer below, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: `to ensure that w[0] + 2 * w[i] (1..N) will sum to exactly 1.0f`  Nope.  https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#floating-pt-errs

Comment: `How can I ensure the sum to be 1.0f on all platforms?`  Use a third-party library that does fixed point arithmetic.  You're not going to achieve this by merely using the `double` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Floating point isn't like that. Even adding the same values can produce different results according to the cpu used.

All you can do is define some accuracy value and ensure that you end up with 1.0 +/- that value.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 0):

Because the precision of float is only 23 bits (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format ), rounding error quickly accumulates therefore even if the rest of code is correct, your sum becomes something like 1.0000001 or 0.9999999 (have you watched it in the debugger or tried to print it to console, by the way?). To improve precision you can replace float with double, but still the sum will not be exactly 1.0: the error will just be smaller, something like 1e-16 instead of 1e-7.
The second thing to do is to replace strict comparison to 1.0 with a range comparison, like:

```
assert(fabs(wSum - 1.0) <= 1e-13 && "Weights sum is not 1.");
```

Here 1e-13 is the epsilon within which you consider two floating-point numbers equal. If you choose to go with float (not double), you may need epsilon like 1e-6 .

Depending on how large your weights are and how many points there are, accumulated error can become larger than that epsilon. In that case you would need special algorithms for keeping the precision higher, such as sorting the numbers by their absolute values prior to summing them up starting with the smallest numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I ensure the sum to be 1.0f on all platforms?

As the other answers (and comments) have stated, you can't achieve this, due to the inexactness of floating point calculations.

One solution is that, instead of using `double`, use a fixed point or multi-precision library such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), [Boost Multiprecision Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html), or one of the many others out there.